# What did the rasool (swl) mean by this?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, women, doubts

It is narrated in https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5191:

> 'Will you heed what I say, O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)? We, the people of Quraish used to have power over our women, but when we arrived at Medina we found that the men (here) were overpowered by their women.'

What is the reason for the rasool (swl) smiling over this? Did he smile because Umar RA's condemnation or was it because the Ansari woman had power over their husbands?